# overwrite variable in parent function from inner function without making variable outside parent function

Tags: r

I am trying to overwrite variable a in 'outer_func' with a value from 'inner_func'. I do not want it to produce a variable a outside of the function 'outer_func'.

```
inner_func <- function(){
  a <<- 30
}

outer_func <- function(){
  a <- 10
  inner_func()
  print(a)
}

outer_func()
```

The output is 10, but it should be 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 alternatives. (1) makes no changes to `inner_func` and (3) makes no changes to `outer_func`.

**1) copy and reset environment of inner_func** Make a copy of `inner_func` within `outer_func` and coerce the current environment to the copy.  No changes are made to `inner_func` and only one line is added to `outer_func` and that both makes the copy and changes its environment.

```
outer_func <- function() {
  a <- 10
  environment(inner_func) <- environment() 
  inner_func()
  print(a)
}

outer_func()
## [1] 30
```

**2) nest inner_func in outer_func** Another way to do this is to nest `inner_func` within `outer_func`.

```
outer_func <- function() {

  inner_func <- function() {
    a <<- 30
  }

  a <- 10
  inner_func()
  print(a)
}

outer_func()
## [1] 30
```

**3) pass environment via arg** Another way is to pass the environment where `a` is located to `inner_func` via an argument.  By making the parent frame the default value of that argument we can avoid having to make any changes to `outer_func`.

```
inner_func <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  envir$a <- 30
}

outer_func <- function() {
  a <- 10
  inner_func()
  print(a)
}

outer_func()
## [1] 30
```

### Note

Any of these can be extended to set particular matrix elements if `a` is defined, say, as this in `outer_func`.

```
a <- matrix(1:4, 2)
```

In (1) and (2) modify `inner_func` to use, for example:

```
a[1,1] <<- 30
```

and in (3) use, for example, this in `inner_func`:

```
envir$a[1,1] <- 30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assign` with the `parent.frame()` (`parent.frame()` s the environment of the outer function, `parent.frame(2)` would be global environment in this case):

```
inner_func <- function(){
  assign("a", 30, envir = parent.frame())
}

outer_func <- function(){
  a <- 10
  inner_func()
  print(a)
}

outer_func()
```

However be careful, because using side effects like makes the code much more complicated, and usually is inadvisable.

Comment: Can I use assign to overwrite specific elements in a matrix? As in assign("visited[row,col]", 30, envir = parent.frame())?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers focus on how to get `outer_func` and `inner_func` to behave like you expect them to behave. I will try to show *why*  they do not do so.

If you redefine `inner_func` to print its parent environment you will see that it is not the environment of the caller but the global environment.

```
inner_func <- function(){
  print(parent.env(environment()))
  a <<- 30
}
```

Now call `outer_func` and see that it is trying to find variable `a` in that environment, not in the environment of `outer_func`.

```
outer_func()
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#[1] 10
```

And when you print `a`, after calling `outer_func`, it has the expected value.

```
a
#[1] 30
```

Function `inner_func` did not find `a` therefore created it in the `GlobalEnv`.

Compare the above with the following. A `inner_func` is defined in `outer_func`. Now the assignment `<<-` finds `a` and changes its value.

```
outer_func2 <- function(){
  inner_func <- function(){
    print(parent.env(environment()))
    a <<- 30
  }

  a <- 10
  inner_func()
  print(a)
}

rm(a)
outer_func2()
#<environment: 0xdd06e18>
#[1] 30
```

But since `outer_func2` does not assign its value, `a` does not exist in the `GlobalEnv`. It was changed in `outer_func` only, the only place where it exists.

```
a
#Error: object 'a' not found
```